# Adding ModelState.AddModelError to my Controller class, without checking for ModelState.IsValid will not have any effect

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have read a book about asp.net MVC 5 and it mentioned that there are multiple approaches to do model validation, for example:-

1. Explicitly Validating a Model in controller
2. Using DataAnnotation

At first I thought that these two approach have exactly the same impact or act in the same way, but I have noted the following:-

If I add `ModelState.AddModelError` to my action method without explicitly checking `ModelState.IsValid` , then I can save my object even if there is a model error as follow (I commented out the `ModelState.IsValid` intentionally):-

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="CountryID,Name")] Country country)
    {

        if (country.Name.StartsWith("a")) {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Name","start with A is not allowed");

       }

   // if (ModelState.IsValid){
        repository.add(country);

        repository.save();
        string s = country.Name;
        string s2 = s;
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        //}          
    }
```

So if I enter a Country.Name which start with “A” ,the repository.save() will not prevent the object from being saved.

While If I replace the explicit check for the Country.Name , by adding a custom metadata validation as follow:-

```
public class NameCheckAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        public override bool IsValid(object value)
        {
            return  !value.ToString().StartsWith("a");
        }
    }
```

Then the `repository.save()`; Will raise the following exception when it tries to add the new country, even if i do not check for ModelState.IsValid

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details. 
  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Source Error: 



Line 5109:        public void Save()
Line 5110:        {
Line 5111:            tms.SaveChanges();
Line 5112:        }
Line 5113:
```

So this means that the two approaches do not act in the same way 100%,as using dataannotation will prevent an object from being added if it violates the dataannotation check, while adding a `ModelState.AddModelError` inside the Controller will not prevent an object from being saved (of course unless i check ModelState.IsValid, before saving the object!). can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because when saving an entity, Entity Framework will perform its own validation on the model (keeping this high level) based on the `DataAnnotations` and the data type rules (cannot save a string to an int for instance).

When you are artificially injecting a ModelState error and then not checking for the `.IsValid()` property, Entity Framework will simply follow the rules for the domain model.

The biggest point from this is that the controller binds returned form values to a model.  If you do not do an `.IsValid()` check, then the data is passed to Entity Framework knows nothing about the bound `ModelState`, including ModelState Errors from the form that you have manually injected, but rather only the rules for the actual Domain Model it is trying to save.

Comment: so is checking the dataannotation for any error prior to saving the object is Entity framework related behaviour? , rather than being an asp.net mvc behaviour ?

Comment: @johnG - Depends on what you call when.  If you call ModelState.IsValid, then MVC is checking the models data annotations and the ModelStateErrors collection for any non-valid properties.  When you call to save to EF, it is checking the model against the data annotations but not the ModelStateErrors collection as it has no idea what that is.

Answer (score 2):

ModelState.AddModelError only adds an error to the existing ModelState. Manually adding error messages with AddModelError is useful for things like custom error messages from business logic checks. Adding a ModelError does no validations on the data, nor does it prevent you from saving data; it's really just a mechanism for collecting errors from various sources.

DataAnnotations are about validating your data. DataAnnotations get checked when the object is created during the HttpPost process, and again when you store data in the database using EntityFramework. An object that fails a check from a DataAnnotation can generate a ModelError, and mark the ModelState as Invalid.

Comment: thanks for the reply, so you mean that this is entity framework behaviour , and not asp.net mvc  behaviour . for example if i use another data access layer (other than EF), then i might not get the same behaviour ?

Comment: DataAnnotations are their own thing; they do interact with Entity Framework, but they also interact with the HTTP processing during Post handling.